# Javascript code behaves proper in IE and improper in firefox

Tags: javascript

i need a clarification regarding my bug.

my requirement is to get the html tag names used in UI dynamically using javascript. Where my code got executed in IE, but it's not proper in Mozila Firefox. 
My Code,

HTML CODE:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option>p_string1</option>
        <option>p_string5</option>
      </select>
    </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
for (i = 0; i < table.rows[0].cells.length; i++) 
{
  pNode[i] = table.getElementsByTagName('td')[i].childNodes[0].nodeName;
}
```

I'm getting the value `#text` instead of the tag name `Select`. But getting the tagname `INPUT` properly..

Comment: if you can modify you markup it is much better to reference your object by an ID rather than td childnodes. I would suggest putting an id on the the input and then referencing that

Comment: ya but I'm writing the code in generic, because actual problem is to append a new row to the existing table with the default format of the table defined by the user in UI.. so instead of getting with the 'id' specifically, i prefer to get the childnodes of the 'td' tag of the specific table, in general.

Answer (score 2):

I would assume this is because firefox (correctly) selects the first childNode, which is whitespace. If you remove ALL white space between the  and the  you'd probably get the correct tag.

EDIT, like this:

```
<td><input
```

I created some jsFiddles to demonstrate the effect:

http://jsfiddle.net/NUEwg/2/

http://jsfiddle.net/zbmeG/1/

EDIT 2:

You could consider using `document.querySelectorAll`. This is support in all browsers except IE6 and IE7. If you don't need support for these, something like this might work.

```
var inner_tags = document.querySelectorAll('td > *')
var first_tag = inner_tags[0].tagName;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey its working... :) but, i just indent the html tags, there is no other extra spaces.. does it will also create the same issue..

Comment: As @Exelian comments text nodes could wrong the result, I updated my solution at http://jsfiddle.net/9YJsd/1/

Answer (score 0):

use the tagName and firstChild element attributes:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_tagname.asp

```
var cells = table.getElementsByTagName('td');
for (i = 0; i < table.rows[0].cells.length; i++) 
{ 
  var cell = cells[i];
  if ( cell && cell.firstChild) {
      result = null;
      for ( position in cell.childNodes){
          if (! result) result = cell.childNodes[position].tagName;
      } 
      pNode[i] = result;
  }
}
```

Notice that line hops and tabulation are noticed by some browsers as TextNodes, which have not tagName, because of that we cycle through the childnodes searching for a defined tagName attribute.
I updated the example at http://jsfiddle.net/9YJsd/1/

Comment: hey, thanks for your support.. `table.getElementsByTagName('td')[i].childNodes[0].tagName` also not working.. what does '#text' means in this context??

Comment: You are welcome, I'm going to put a more complete answer if you don't mind